# When `depends_on` is being used in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker-compose

When `depends_on` is being used in docker-compose.yml?

When a web app has connection to a database, in the docker compose yml file, I see these two examples. One is with `depends_on` and one is without `depends_on`.

In one tutorial, I see that there is no `depends_on` is being used.

```
version: '3'
services:
  ms-sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  book-app:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8090:80"
```

In another example, I see that `depends_on` is being used.

```
version: "3"
services:
    api:
        build: 
          context: ..
          dockerfile: CF.Api/Dockerfile 
        ports:
            - "8888:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's understand what `depends_on` means. The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/):

[image]

Based on that description, it's clear that in your second example, namely

```
version: "3"
services:
    api:
        build: 
          context: ..
          dockerfile: CF.Api/Dockerfile 
        ports:
            - "8888:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

`depends_on` specifies that the `api` will need the `db`, so `db` as a service needs to be started before `api`, when `docker-compose up` is being executed.

Also, if `docker-compose api` is being executed, that will also start the `db` service before the `api` service is started. Also, `docker-compose stop` will first stop the `api` and only then stop the `db` service.

So, first `db` is started as a service and then `api` is started as a service as well. Note, that it is possible that `api` is started before `db` is ready.

Comment: another word when `depends_on` is specified, both api service and db will be under the same stack. when `depends_on` is not specified, both api service and db will be under the 2 different stack, right?

Comment: @Steve I think so, but I'm not sure. Do you have a way to test this?